# Significado de "paradigma": o alfabeto é um paradigma?

Tags: significado, significado-em-contexto

Estava pesquisando sobre paradigmas e o conceito que muitos sites utilizam é o seguinte:

> Paradigma é um modelo ou padrão a seguir.
>
> um exemplo que serve como modelo; padrão.

Tendo em vista essas informações, logo me veio a dúvida:

Os alfabeto define o modo com que iremos aprender determinada linguagem. Como o português.

**Logo ele é um paradigma?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Não**, isso é uma interpretação incorreta do que é um paradigma.

Nós podemos dizer coisas como:

> Há vários paradigmas de escrita. **Um paradigma é o alfabeto**, que consiste, grosso modo, em representar cada som por um símbolo diferente. Outro paradigma é o silabário, que consiste em representar cada sílaba por um símbolo diferente.

Repara que na frase acima, “alfabeto” não se refere ao nosso alfabeto em particular, que é o latino, nem ao grego nem a qualquer outro alfabeto em particular; refere-se ao alfabeto em geral, em abstrato — à forma, ou modelo, ou sistema, ou paradigma de escrita (neste contexto estas quatro palavras são sinónimos) que todos os alfabetos concretos seguem. O [artigo da Wikipédia sobre o alfabeto](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfabeto) diz que “alfabeto ou abecedário é uma forma de escrita […]” — onde está “forma” poderíamos escrever “paradigma”. Cada alfabeto particular não é um paradigma, mas segue o paradigma comum a todos os alfabetos.

De qualquer modo, mesmo neste sentido geral, o alfabeto é um paradigma de escrita, não da língua. Outras coisas que não são paradigmas da língua:

- O uso da segunda pessoa plural («vós») no Norte interior de Portugal é um paradigma comunicacional, da comunicação. Mas não da língua.
- O soneto é um dos paradigmas da poesia, mas não da língua em si.
- Poder-se-ia ainda defender que o formalismo verborreico seja um paradigma comunicacional ou comportamental — conquanto não da língua em si.

Já a concordância de género, sim, é um paradigma da língua.
A capitalização (?) dos nomes próprios, mas não dos comuns.
A intonação crescente no fim das interrogações. («Não é asSIM?»)
Etc.

Comment: Eu sugiro aqui uma clarificação. O alfabeto enquanto paradigma de escrita é a representação de cada som por um símbolo (embora nos alfabetos reais a correspondência esteja longe de ser biunívoca): cada um dos alfabetos particulares--latino, grego, cirílico, etc.--segue esse paradigma; mas nenhum alfabeto concreto é um paradigma (talvez pudéssemos dizer que o primeiro é). Do mesmo modo, o soneto que é o paradigma é a estrutura geral; o "erros meus, má fortuna, amor ardente" não é paradigma. No soneto toda a gente percebe que é o "soneto abstrato"; já "alfabeto" pode ser interpretado >>

Comment: na tua resposta como o nosso alfabeto, o latino.

Comment: Percebo, @Jacinto, mas não sei como clarificar isso. Não me queres ajeitar tu a resposta? :)

Comment: Vê lá se gostas.

Comment: @Jacinto gosto mais, mas não ficou perfeito. Tem, por exemplo, usos de "paradigma de língua" e de "paradigma da língua" na mesma frase, que para mim indicam significados diferentes. Mas acho que para a resposta que é, já teve um cachê de atenção alto suficiente, e vai ficar mesmo assim que já está ótima.

Comment: Muda-se para *da*, ora essa.

Answer (score 1):

O alfabeto não define o modo que aprendemos um idioma. Existem diversos modos dos quais podemos aprender uma língua independentemente de saber ou não o alfabeto.

Pode-se considerar o alfabeto um *paradigma de escrita*, pois não dependemos dele para de fato sermos capazes de nos comunicar verbamente, obviamente um complementa o outro, não é possível uma pessoa alcançar fluência sem dominar a escrita, porém não saber o mesmo, não o impede de aprender uma língua.

Infelizmente a realidade do analfabetismo ainda é presente em alguns países ao redor do mundo, porém os analfabetos são a prova viva de que **ler/escrever** não tem absolutamente nada a ver com **falar** o idioma.

Comment: Escreves que «não é possível uma pessoa alcançar fluência sem dominar a escrita», mas depois mencionas os analfabetos. Eles são fluentes na língua portuguesa porque a falam nativamente.

Comment: @ANeves ser fluente em uma língua significa que você domina completamente a **fala, leitura e escrita** do mesmo. Se uma pessoa sabe falar o idioma mas não sabe escrevê-lo, então ela não é fluente, portanto, ela se encaixa como *analfabeto*.

Comment: Ah, que curioso, para mim não é assim. Abri uma pergunta sobre isso: https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4699/o-que-significa-ser-fluente