# O que significa «ser fluente»?

Tags: significado

O que significa «ser fluente numa língua»?
Apenas que se tem agilidade no uso de uma língua? Ou implica literacia?

Expondo mais longamente:

Na pergunta [O Alfabeto é um paradigma?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4687/o-alfabeto-%c3%a9-um-paradigma/4698) , alguém referiu que alguém fluente numa língua é

> [alguém que] domina completamente a fala, leitura e escrita do mesmo. Se uma pessoa sabe falar o idioma mas não sabe escrevê-lo, então ela não é fluente, portanto, ela se encaixa como analfabeto.

Mas esta não é a noção que eu tenho.
A minha noção de fluente não implica leitura ou escrita, apenas destreza. E diz-me que um nativo é fluente na sua língua, porque a usa bem e com facilidade; não tropeça no significado das palavras; entende subtilezas; e entende o essa comunicação influenciada por contextos.

Um poeta pastor analfabeto seria, portanto, fluente.
E alguém bem letrado, inteligente, e capaz de usar avançadamente uma língua não seria fluente se o fizesse lentamente e com apoio de dicionários, por muito bem que lesse e escrevesse.
Mas considero o Stephen Hawking perfeitamente fluente em inglês, apesar de ele [comunicar de forma muito lenta e tosca](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IGorZafXOFY&t=80).
(Este discurso dele foi pré-programado; em tempo real seria  l-e-n-t-o.)

- Então, qual é o significado de fluente?

Comment: Se não me deixarem um comentário a explicar o que precisa de ser melhorado ou corrigido na pergunta, como querem que adivinhe?

Comment: "Close reason: primarily opinion based", porquê? Quero saber o que significa «ser fluente numa língua». A definição de um termo é *opinion-based*? Só deste termo, ou de termos em geral? Não percebo o que fazer acerca disto.

Comment: "Close reason: too broad", porquê? Sei que não tenho mais que uma questão nesta pergunta, então qual será o problema... Devo reduzir o tamanho da pergunta? Evitar explicar detalhadamente o meu problema? Não percebo o que fazer acerca disto.

Answer (score 2):

O termo "fluente" vem obviamente da palavra fluir ou atuar como um fluido.
Logo, falar sem tropeços, contornando perfeitamente os obstáculos.

Portanto falar com uma pessoa "fluente" em um idioma significa que esta pessoa fala perfeitamente, entende todas as nuances, não "tropeça" em termos básicos.
Uma pessoa fluente praticamente faz com que o interlocutor nem sequer perceba que aquele idioma não é o idioma nativo dela, mas não obrigatoriamente a pessoa precisa ser culta, letrada ou mesmo alfabetizada no idioma.

Answer (score 0):

O meu argumento na pergunta [O Alfabeto é um paradigma?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4687/o-alfabeto-%C3%A9-um-paradigma/4696?noredirect=1#comment12434_4696), era defendendo que uma pessoa não pode ser fluente em um idioma sem saber ler ou escrever e que portanto, se encaixa como analfabeto. Com uma simples busca sobre sua definição no Google me apareceu o seguinte resultado:

[image: analfabeto]

---

> E diz-me que um nativo é fluente na sua língua, porque a usa bem e com facilidade; não tropeça no significado das palavras; entende subtilezas; e entende o essa comunicação influenciada por contextos.

A sua definição de fluente está correta, realmente um nativo ou fluente na sua língua possui todas essas características citadas por você. Porém nessa sua definição se está levando em conta o fato da pessoa já possuir uma instrução/educação básica do idioma, se a pessoa nunca leu na vida, obviamente seu vocabulário será limitado a sua bolha social e incapaz também será incapaz de transpor suas ideias através da escrita, tornando-se um individuo limitado.

Você já morou no exterior? Se sim talvez se identifique com o que já passou comigo, eu estava em uma mesa de bar com uma alemã, uma norueguesa, um francês, e um colombiano e estavamos todos conversando em inglês.

O meu amigo francês sabia falar inglês, utilizava corretamente os tempos verbais, os pronomes e tudo mais, porém o problema era a sua pronúncia. Muitas vezes nós tinhamos que pedir para ele repetir duas vezes ou mesmo ditar algumas palavras, agora eu te pergunto se essa sua "fluência" se aplica neste caso.

E se ele não soubesse como ditar as palavras? Provavelmente ele se frustaria em não poder expressar sua ideia. É por isso que eu digo, não dá pra considerar uma pessoa fluente, por mais que ela fale perfeitamente o idioma, a comunicação interpessoal é limitada sem a leitura e ou escrita.

Se você se candidatasse para uma vaga de emprego que é necessário fluência em japonês, você acredita que teria chance com apenas a comunicação verbal? Em 99% das vezes (se não 100%) te descartariam como candidato por possuir tamanha limitação.

Comment: 1. Não acho que falta de instrução implique falta de fluência. Diplomas não fazem as pessoas especiais, há por aí muito sotôr burro... há alguma correlação, só. 2. Do Francês: se for *só* uma questão de sotaque, eu acho que **sim**, que o francês é fluente; um açoriano não deixa de ser fluente em português por a sua pronúncia ser [difícil de entender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HNv4cUU_yzE). 3. O argumento da fluência como requisito para um emprego parece-me bom e forte, e vale a pena expandi-lo.